# Getting the area of a polygon from Google Earth or .xyz digital elevation model INCLUDING area due to topography

Tags: kml, topography, matlab, xyz

I'm doing some analysis for a study on geomorphology. For this I'm comparing the 'bumpiness' of lava fields to the 'bumpiness' of the surroundings. What I'm trying to do for this is measure the ratio of the actual area inside a polygon (so including topography) to the area inside the polygon disregarding topography. So a a value >> 1 would be quite bumpy etc.

I have all the cut outs in .xyz so Lat Long, Elev and all the cut outs as .kml but I'm wondering if there is a straightforward way to do this before I launch into trying to code it myself. I have and can use MatLab!! I can take the area disregarding elevation straight from Google Earth so this bit is not a problem!